# array_agg in QueryDSL 4

Tags: postgresql, querydsl

I would like to know, how to make an array_agg in QueryDSL 4.
I've writte this SQL request :

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(id), ',') as id,
id_semaine_type, jour_semaine, heure_debut, heure_fin,
array_to_string(array_agg(media),',') AS media,
array_to_string(array_agg(id_classe_type_population), ',') as id_classe_type_population
FROM accueil.plage_ouverture 
WHERE id_semaine_type = 6
GROUP BY id_semaine_type, jour_semaine, heure_debut, heure_fin
ORDER BY jour_semaine, heure_debut, heure_fin;
```

What is the way to make :

```
array_to_string(array_agg(id), ',') as id
```

in QueryDSL ?

Have you any idea to solve my problem ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do this in `querydsl-sql`? Or `querydsl-jpa`?